# .cache/fontfonfig directory fills infinitely courtesy mate-settings-daemon

Tags: linux, manjaro, mate, fontconfig

Noob here. I'm running Manjaro Linux with MATE as Desktop Environment. For some weird reason, `mate-settings-daemon` fills up my `.cache/fontconfig` directory infinitely. I use `fc-cache` to generate font caches, which come to a meagre 2000ish files. But, on startup, `mate-settings-daemon` runs and fills it to over a million files. I've tried disabling compiz, but the problem remained. Everytime caja restarts because I quit it with `caja -q`, font caches get created too. It makes no sense to me, whatsoever. The cache generated by `fc-cache` seem to have no problem since the fonts work well.

It'd be e boon, if you could even point out my ignorance about the settings (couldn't find anything relevant using `dconf-editor` either).

I've tried running mate-settings-daemon with the debug flag, but the output doesn't seem helpful at all. Nevertheless, here it is:

```
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): GLib-GIO-DEBUG: 09:35:51.442: _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation dconf (DConfSettingsBackend) for ‘gsettings-backend’
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.442: watch_fast: "/org/mate/debug/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.451: watch_established: "/org/mate/debug/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): GLib-GIO-DEBUG: 09:35:51.463: _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation gvfs (GDaemonVfs) for ‘gio-vfs’
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.524: watch_fast: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.524: watch_established: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.524: watch_fast: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/keybindings/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.525: watch_established: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/keybindings/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.525: watch_fast: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/a11y-keyboard/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.525: watch_established: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/a11y-keyboard/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.525: watch_fast: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/background/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.526: watch_established: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/background/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.526: watch_fast: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/mpris/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.526: watch_established: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/mpris/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.526: watch_fast: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/typing-break/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.527: watch_established: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/typing-break/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.527: watch_fast: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/smartcard/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.527: watch_established: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/smartcard/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.527: watch_fast: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/xsettings/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.528: watch_established: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/xsettings/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.528: watch_fast: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/clipboard/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.528: watch_established: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/clipboard/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.528: watch_fast: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/keyboard/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.528: watch_established: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/keyboard/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.529: watch_fast: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/xrdb/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.529: watch_established: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/xrdb/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.529: watch_fast: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/rfkill/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.529: watch_established: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/rfkill/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.530: watch_fast: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/mouse/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.530: watch_established: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/mouse/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.530: watch_fast: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.530: watch_established: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.531: watch_fast: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/a11y-settings/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.531: watch_established: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/a11y-settings/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.531: watch_fast: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/xrandr/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.531: watch_established: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/xrandr/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.532: watch_fast: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/sound/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.532: watch_established: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/sound/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.532: watch_fast: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/housekeeping/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.533: watch_established: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/housekeeping/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.541: watch_fast: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/xrandr/" (establishing: 0, active: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.560: watch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/peripherals/mouse/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.560: watch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/interface/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.560: watch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/sound/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.561: watch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/font-rendering/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.561: watch_established: "/org/mate/desktop/peripherals/mouse/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.561: watch_established: "/org/mate/desktop/interface/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.561: watch_established: "/org/mate/desktop/sound/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.561: watch_established: "/org/mate/desktop/font-rendering/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.805: watch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/sound/" (establishing: 0, active: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.953: watch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/keybindings/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.959: watch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/background/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.966: watch_established: "/org/mate/desktop/keybindings/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.966: watch_established: "/org/mate/desktop/background/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.980: watch_fast: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/housekeeping/" (establishing: 0, active: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.980: watch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/thumbnail-cache/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.981: watch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/typing-break/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.982: watch_established: "/org/mate/desktop/thumbnail-cache/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:51.986: watch_established: "/org/mate/desktop/typing-break/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:52.813: watch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/peripherals/keyboard/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:52.814: watch_established: "/org/mate/desktop/peripherals/keyboard/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:52.882: watch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/peripherals/keyboard/general/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:52.882: watch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/peripherals/keyboard/kbd/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:52.882: watch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/peripherals/keyboard/general/" (establishing: 1, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:52.882: watch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/peripherals/keyboard/kbd/" (establishing: 1, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:52.883: watch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/peripherals/keyboard/kbd/" (establishing: 2, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:52.883: watch_established: "/org/mate/desktop/peripherals/keyboard/general/" (establishing: 2)
[1574827552,000,xklavier.c:xkl_engine_start_listen/]    The backend does not require manual layout management - but it is provided by the application
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:52.883: watch_established: "/org/mate/desktop/peripherals/keyboard/kbd/" (establishing: 3)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:52.909: watch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/peripherals/keyboard/kbd/" (establishing: 0, active: 3)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:52.909: unwatch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/peripherals/keyboard/kbd/" (active: 4, establishing: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:52.910: watch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/peripherals/keyboard/general/" (establishing: 0, active: 2)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:52.910: watch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/peripherals/keyboard/kbd/" (establishing: 0, active: 3)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:52.910: watch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/peripherals/keyboard/indicator/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:52.910: watch_established: "/org/mate/desktop/peripherals/keyboard/indicator/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:52.936: watch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/peripherals/mouse/" (establishing: 0, active: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:52.936: watch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/peripherals/touchpad/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:52.936: watch_established: "/org/mate/desktop/peripherals/touchpad/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:52.960: watch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/accessibility/keyboard/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:52.960: watch_established: "/org/mate/desktop/accessibility/keyboard/" (establishing: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:35:52.973: watch_fast: "/org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/" (establishing: 0, active: 1)
(msd-locate-pointer:23955): GLib-GIO-DEBUG: 09:35:52.990: _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation gvfs (GDaemonVfs) for ‘gio-vfs’
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:47:26.753: watch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/accessibility/keyboard/" (establishing: 0, active: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:47:26.753: unwatch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/accessibility/keyboard/" (active: 2, establishing: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:47:27.040: watch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/accessibility/keyboard/" (establishing: 0, active: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:47:27.041: unwatch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/accessibility/keyboard/" (active: 2, establishing: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:47:55.262: watch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/accessibility/keyboard/" (establishing: 0, active: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:47:55.262: unwatch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/accessibility/keyboard/" (active: 2, establishing: 0)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:49:21.170: watch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/accessibility/keyboard/" (establishing: 0, active: 1)
(mate-settings-daemon:23930): dconf-DEBUG: 09:49:21.171: unwatch_fast: "/org/mate/desktop/accessibility/keyboard/" (active: 2, establishing: 0)
```

My versions are:

- mate-settings-daemon: 1.22.1-1
- Manajro:              18.1.3
- Linux Kernel:         4.19.85-1-MANJARO

I really have no clue & there's nothing similar on any forum. The only solution I've to try might be to fc-cache & make the fontconfig directory readable only.